# What is the solution for "Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure."

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am doing selenium program and have written the script for Firefox browser. When I run the test, it opens a browser, but nothing happens after that. Console has below error:
"Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure."
What is the solution for this?

I am using code as :-

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","C:\\gecko‌​driver-v0.18.0-win32‌​\\geckodriver.exe");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your selenium jars and geckodriver. Update your firefox browser too.
This problem is happening when the jars are too old to handle new changes in browser.

Downlaod selenium jars :-

http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

Download geckodriver :-

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

You are using wrong gecko parameter :-

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\gecko‌​driver-v0.18.0-win32‌​\\geckodriver.exe");
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: I have latest driver and jar files only, the same given on above links.

Comment: are you using geckodriver also?

Comment: yes this path is given: System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","C:\\geckodriver-v0.18.0-win32\\geckodriver.exe");

Comment: how to deal with drop-downs and values in drop-down if I want to select it through selenium webdriver?

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer :) .... refer link to deal with dropdown :- https://www.guru99.com/select-option-dropdown-selenium-webdriver.html